# Aggregation and other arrows in Eclipse modeling framework

Tags: eclipse, frameworks, uml, modeling

Is there any option in **Eclipse modeling framework** to choose different arrow than Association or Generalization arrow? I mean something like "aggregation" or association line without arrow  in the end. In EMF I can "draw" only this: ---> and this ---<>. But there are much more like: ---|>, or ---(+) and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ecore itself supports only EClass.eReferences (association) and EClass.eSuperTypes (generalization).  EReferences can be bidirectional in which cases there is no arrow head, and an EReference can be a containment, in which case there is a black diamond.  That's all there is.  You'll need a UML tool like Papyrus to support the full UML repertoire.